# How to capture audio together with video in VLC?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, audio, vlc-media-player, audio-recording

I am currently capturing my desktop in VLC as such :

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> ( capture options )
- then I choose capture device `Desktop`
- then on the bottom I choose `Play` -> `Convert`
- choose a file to save to and some options (including turning audio on)
- then after finishing the stream/saving I have a video file with no audio

How can I include audio capturing ?

**EDIT**

My OS is Windows 7 ( but I might need to do this on ubuntu as well ).

Comment: What version of VLC are you using?  On my version, the video device drop down box is literally right next to the audio device drop down.